# Why did Microsoft Remote Desktop stop sending Ctr+Alt+Insert to host session?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

In Windows 7 update KB2830477, Remote Desktop for Windows does not sent anymore the key combination Ctrl+Alt+Insert, even if you explicitly configure your connection to send all keys to the host.  With Windows 7 you have the option of skipping installation of the update, but with Windows 8.1 you do not even have that option.

The first level of support of Microsoft does not seem to know any reason for this change besides acknowledging that Microsoft actually changed it and that it is not a bug.

It obviously breaks any existing workflows that rely on an application on the host responding to Ctrl+Alt+Insert. So the disadvantadges of this decision by Microsoft are clear.

What are the advantages of this change?  What does it try to fix?  AFAIK, Ctr+Alt+Insert is not even a hotkey for the Windows Remote Desktop program.

Comment: Ctrl+alt+insert passes the ctrl+alt+delete combination to the remote session. I've been using this combination for quite a while and it works in a lot of different remote software.

Comment: @NathanC That's Ctrl+Alt+End that sends the Ctrl+Alt+Del keystroke. Ctrl+Alt+Insert shouldn't be captured to my knowledge. It might be leftovers from when Alt+Insert was used to send Alt+Esc (cycles through programs, like Alt+Tab but without the little menu thing).

Comment: @ChrisS Really? I've been using ctrl+alt+insert and it's been working for me.

Comment: Does nothing for me, what OS are you on? I'm on 8.1 connecting to 2008R2 at the moment.

Comment: @ChrisS - same here...does nothing for me either...exact same environment as you.  (i'll delete this comment soon to quit muddying up his question).

Comment: @NathanC For the issue, I was referring specifically to Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection software, the one that already comes bundled with the OS, not to other emulations.  Microsoft made a change and I cannot make any sense out it.

Comment: Pep, I'm guessing this is you? http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b2b20043-ac03-4f82-a600-84ab0da32bb2/kb2830477-filters-ctrlaltins-on-remote-desktop?forum=w7itproinstall  -- sorry mate...I don't know why they removed the functionality.  Maybe to piss off VMware and promote hyper-v? :)

Comment: @TheCleaner No, it is a coworker in the team. We are a hyper-v shop.  I've just found a workaround for Windows 8.0 and 8.1: install the Remote Desktop from the App Store (the one with the same red icon that appears in the Remote Desktop released by Microsoft for Mac last month).  In the Remote Desktop from the App Store, Ctrl+Alt+Insert is not filtered.  Still I do not understand why Microsoft removed the functionality in the old Remote Desktop Connection program.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

To use the Ctrl-Alt-Insert combo in Microsoft RDP, perform the following configuration:
Open the Remote Desktop Connection utility.
Click Options.
Open the Local Resources tab.
Change the value for Apply Windows key combinations option under Keyboard to On the rem

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1025282

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue with Windows 8.1 and Server 2003 - 2012

After some investigation I found this was due to third party software (IOBIT WINDOWS 8 START MENU)

When exiting the application all the regular key forwarding within the TS works normally.

This may or may not be your issue however I thought I should mention it here.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, it is not the case.  For 8.1, we use the other Remote Desktop (the one in the App Store).